# jQuery UI Datepicker working on Chrome but not on Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, safari, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've been testing a page with a few jQuery UI elements and Safari has been giving me some headache. Check out the link: http://data-buckeye-590.appspot.com/index

The first text input uses a jQuery autocomplete and both date fields use datepickers. Now, the date pickers work perfectly on Chrome but not on Safari. Any clue why this happens?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/imports.html">
    </head>
    <body fullbleed layout vertical unresolved>
        <h1>Datas de entrada e sa&iacute;da no hotel</h1>
        <input type="text" id="form_date_in" autocomplete="off" readonly placeholder="Entrada">
        <input type="text" id="form_date_out" autocomplete="off" readonly placeholder="Sa&iacute;da">
        <script  src="scripts/main.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {

    $("#form_date_in").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: "+1w",
        maxDate: "+330d",
        onClose: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#form_date_out").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#form_date_out").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        maxDate: "+330d"
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide a smaller example that includes only the elements required to reproduce this error. Most of the code you have provided has nothing to do with the problem you are describing.

Comment: You're right. I've cleaned up the code a little.

Comment: Another piece of information. Going through Safari's web inspector I noticed it throws an error and either of these date fields are focused:

`[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'b.ownerDocument.defaultView')
 (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js, line 3) `

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but not quite the cause for this issue. I had installed jQuery through Bower and I was running the latest version jQuery Core 1.11.2.

I linked to a previous version (1.10.2) through jQuery CDN version and Datepicker is working perfectly.